# Basic integration identity of continuous even function.

Tags: integration

> Prove for a continuous even function $f$,  $$\int^0_{-b}f(x)dx = \int^b_{0}f(x)dx$$

---

Let $u(x) = -x\ \ \ \ \ u^{'}(x) = -1$

$$\int^0_{-b}f(x)dx = -\int^0_{u(-b)}f(u)du = \int^b_{0}f(u)du$$

---

What should I do now ? I have got the limits correct on the integral but I have changed the variable to $u$.

Comment: The variable is irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable of integration, in your case $u$ is just a dummy variable! You can replace it with $x$, $y$ or an smiley face.

The intuition here is you are summing the value of a function at points over infinitesimal lengths, you can call these points whatever you want, $u$ or $x$, as long as your choice is consistent with what you call the lengths, $du$ or $dx$ respectively.

Comment: Almost downvoted for suggesting a smileyface as a variable... never do that (+1 though, good answer)

Comment: @vrugtehagel haha, as long as you can order emojis it seems legit

Comment: This has to be the biggest facepalm every. I just skimmed this part the chapter thinking it is irrelevant. I realised my mistake just after @vrugtehagel posted his comment. Idiot me.

Comment: @A---B don't beat yourself up, it's an incredibly common mistake

Comment: @A---B no problem, take your time!